# C++ Boost::asio x64 async_send fails with error 10014 (WSAEFAULT)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

We have a C++ program I'm porting to x64 in Visual Studio 2017. This program uses boost asio to send data over TCP connections. The code works fine in 32 bit. But when I build and then run it for x64 the async_send fails with error 10014 (WSAEFAULT), I debugged into the boost asio code and the culprit predictably is the call to the windows method WSASend (in boost\asio\detail\impl\win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx

This is my relevant code (dumbed down to exclude other possible causes) that currently fails.
At this point the connection is set up successfully and I try to send the first data over the connection:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> testWriteBuffer(16,0);
boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket,
              boost::asio::buffer(&testWriteBuffer[0], testWriteBuffer.size()),
                                   boost::bind(&CTIPCTCPConnection::IOHandleWrite, boost::static_pointer_cast<CTIPCTCPConnection>(shared_from_this()), NextMessage->IsLowPriority(),boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

where m_Socket is this:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket      m_Socket;
```

Not sure whether this is relevant, this is the command line for the compiler (we built the boost library with the same options):

```
/GS /W4 /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\..\..\Export\Include" /I"..\Include" /I"..\..\Include" /I"..\..\..\Include" /I"..\..\..\Ref\Include" /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl- /Fd"C:\Workspaces\grpMiddleware\gc_AsioCom_x64\AsioCommunication\Test\Vc150\Debug_x64\\Test.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /Zp1 /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_WIN32_WINNT=0X603" /D "WINVER=0X603" /D "_MBCS" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_TOKHEIM_FUELPOS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /FC /Fa"C:\Workspaces\grpMiddleware\gc_AsioCom_x64\AsioCommunication\Test\Vc150\Debug_x64\\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"C:\Workspaces\grpMiddleware\gc_AsioCom_x64\AsioCommunication\Test\Vc150\Debug_x64\\" /Fp"C:\Workspaces\grpMiddleware\gc_AsioCom_x64\AsioCommunication\Test\Vc150\Debug_x64\\Testd.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Comment: Unless you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, it's going to be *very* hard to help you in a meaningful way (other than to *guess*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seems kinda bad looking at the few lines you posted is that the `std::vector<unsigned char> testWriteBuffer(16,0)` most likely lives on stack and thus gets destroyed after you call `async_write` but it should be alive until the completion routine runs. As you can see in the documentation of [boost::asio::buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)

> It is the responsibility of the application to ensure the memory region remains valid until it is no longer required for an I/O operation.

**UPDATE**

Well yeah, WSABUF suffers from the `/Zp1`, see this simple example:

```
//#pragma pack(push, 1)
#include <Winsock2.h>

#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WSABUF buffer;
    printf("size - %zu, offset of buf - %zu, offset of len - %zu", sizeof(buffer), offsetof(decltype(buffer), buf), offsetof(decltype(buffer), len));
    return 0;
}
```

Without the pack it gives - `size - 16, offset of buf - 8, offset of len - 0`,
with - `size - 12, offset of buf - 4, offset of len - 0` on x64. Can't you isolate the boost i/o part and compile boost without `/Zp1`?

Comment: Yes, this is true. This was done by me to simplify the code (the original code does this properly with shared pointers). But it doesn't matter as the code fails even before the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: @GertCorthout, yeah, `/Zp1` affects `WSABUF`, can't you isolate the i/o code to compile boost without it?

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Some additional searching unearthed this sort of bug report to MS:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/194354/64-bit-builds-may-not-work-if-packing-changed.html

We will use:

#pragma pack(push, 1)

*STRUCT DEFINTION*

#pragma pack(pop)


around the data definitions we serialize and send out.

Comment: Yes, that is a common approach to use those pragamas around structs that need alignment. I'd say using `/Zp1` for a whole project seems weird.

Comment: I agree, this was done as a quick and dirty short cut some 15-20 years ago. As usual those sort of things come back to bite you twice as hard sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason for this was the /Zp1 compile flag (struct member alignment). Once I removed this from the project and all its dependencies it worked fine again. Removing this does open up a whole new can of worms wrt backwards compatibility though.